# Python3: Counting occurrence of characters in a nested dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, n-gram, defaultdict

I'm currently working on a small piece of code and I seem to have run into a roadblock. I was wondering if it's possible to find the most common occurrence of a character that follows a specific group of characters?

For example, say I have the following sentence:

`"fishies are super neat, a fish is a good pet. also, fishing is for dads."`

How would could I determine, for example, the most common character that occurs after the fragment `"fish"`?

In this specific example, doing it by hand, I get something like this:

`{"i": 2, " ": 1}`

Currently, I have this chunk of code written to grab the "fish" portion of the word:

```
b = Class(n, 'file.txt')
ngrams = [b.file[i:i+n] for i in range(len(b.file)-1)]
```

this will break up all of the text into chunks of 4 like so: `['fish', 'ishi', 'shie', 'hies', 'ies ', 'es a'.....]`

My goal is to combine these two thoughts so that I can print something that looks like the following:

`{'fish' : {'i':2, ' ':1} ..... }`

I also currently have a defaultdict defined in `__init__` like so: `self.counts=defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))`

This is the closest I can get to achieving my desired solution, although I am unsure how to grab the individual characters that follow and how to count those characters:

`b.counts = {i : { j : 5 for j in ngrams } for i in ngrams }`

`5` is merely a placeholder so I could see what printed. `j in ngrams` was also a placeholder to see what printed. Any input or ideas from anyone would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what  2 and 1 represent in`{"i": 2, " ": 1}` ?

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb the occurrence of those characters after the 'fish' string! 
 occurs twice: "i" occurs once in "fishies" and once in "fishing". " " occurs after "a fish is"

Comment: why you did not count the 'i' in "is"? also white space occurred multiple times after the word 'fish'

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb I want to count the occurrence of a *character* after the string "fish". The character after 'fish' is the white space, not the 'i'. White space only occurs once after "fish".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

raw_string = "fishies are super neat, a fish is a good pet. also, fishing is for dads."

key =  ['fish', 'ishi', 'shie', 'hies']
out = {}
for item in key:
    data = []
    for word in re.findall(item+'.', raw_string):
        data.append(word[-1])
    results = {item:data.count(item) for item in data}
    out[item] = results
```

**Output:**

```
{'fish': {'i': 2, ' ': 1}, 'ishi': {'e': 1, 'n': 1}, 'shie': {'s': 1}, 'hies': {' ': 1}}
```

Comment: Very cool! I didn't think to import re. Though, I'm wondering if there's a way to make this more universal, so it works for more than just "fish"? Say I have a list such as: ['fish', 'ishi', 'shie', 'hies', ..... ]. How would you go about iterating through that list to add 'ishi', 'shie, and 'hies' to the dictionary alongside 'fish'?

Comment: I noticed that in the output, the keys print out an additional letter. Like how "fish" becomes "fishi". I've been messing around with the code a little, but can't seem to pinpoint the problem/how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: @larn I don't understand you problem. Can you explain with some example?

Comment: Well, if you look at the list "key", we saw ['fish', 'ishi', 'shie', 'hies']. However, in the final output from the code, we get {'fishi: {....}, 'ishin': {.....}, 'shies': {......}, 'hies':{......}} 
So, in the final output, each item from the list "key" is given an additional character. 
"fish" becomes "fishi", for example. "ishi" becomes "ishin". 
Instead of the four character string that appeared in the list, the dictionary prints out five characters.

Comment: @larn yep, sorry loop variable is doubled. code updated

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

sentence = "fishies are super neat, a fish is a good pet. also, fishing is for dads."
word = 'fish'
result = {}
result[word] = Counter(re.findall(f'{word}(.)', sentence, flags=re.IGNORECASE))

print(result)
```

Note that this will also count cases where the fragment you are looking for appears in the middle of a word. If you only want to count words that start with the fragment, you could use something like `re.findall(f'\\W{word}(.)')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
sentence = "fishies are super neat, a fish is a good pet. also, fishing is for dads."
s_list = sentence.split("fish")
stat = {}
for i in s_list[1:]:
    if i[0] in stat.keys():
        stat[i[0]] += 1
    else:
        stat[i[0]] = 1

print(stat)
```